# javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date_notify' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "notifications.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(responseJSON) {
            if (responseJSON.length > 0) {
                document.title = document.title.replace(/^(?:\(\d+\))?/, "(" + responseJSON.length + ") ")
                for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
                    console.log(responseJSON[i].date_notify')
                }
            }
        }, error : function(x) {
            console.log(x.responseText)
        }
    })
```

In chrome I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date_notify' of undefined

And I figured out at this part `for (var i=0; i<10; i++)` should be replace to `for (var i=0; i<responseJSON.length; i++)` the problem is I only want to have 10 results... in my sql part I didn't **LIMIT** the query. here's my query

```
SELECT users.lastname, users.firstname, users.screenname, notifications.notify_id, 
notifications.tagged_by, notifications.user_id, notifications.post_id,                                                        
notifications.type, notifications.action, notifications.date_notify,
notifications.notify_id
FROM website.users users INNER JOIN website.notifications notifications
ON (users.user_id = notifications.user_id)
WHERE notifications.user_id = ? and notifications.action = ?
ORDER BY notifications.notify_id DESC
//LIMIT 10
```

Is there any possible way to change this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `AND`ed conditional in your loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<responseJSON.length && i<10; i++)
```

This way the loop cuts out when `i` either exceeds the number of entries or reaches 10, whichever happens first.  If the number of entries is less than 10, the first condition becomes false first, and if there are more than 10 records, the second condition becomes false first.

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT your SQL query.  There's no reason to consume network bandwidth and server resources for data you'll not use, say nothing of the potential security concern if the data is sensitive.